# Best way to make simple callback

Tags: java, php, closures

I'm in doubt of how works Java. I need do a code like it (in PHP):

```
array_map(function($object){ ... });
```

And on Java, I close to it:

```
this.addTransition(new CallerTransition() {
    @Override
    protected void execute() {
        // Do something with _this_ here
    }
});
```

Translating: I need know if exists a better way to work with closures-like.

**Notes**: `CallerTransition` is subtyped `Transition`. addTransition requires a `Transition`. The `execute` method will be executed by `addTransition`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java doesn't have lambda functions or function-based closures, so I'm afraid anonymous classes are the best way to go.

Comment: You mean, the same way that I'm doing?

Comment: Lambda expressions are currently planned for Java 8 as JSR 335 per JSR 337 - http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/

Comment: bad luck, you'll have to use anonymous classes.